# Popular dropdown list com banco de dados em Controller do Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

Estou com dificuldade de encontrar uma maneira de popular um dropdown no Controller e passar para o view. Pois dessa maneira que estou fazendo quando entro na tela para atualizar o dropdown não retorna com o valor que já estava.

Estou fazendo dessa forma (controller):

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/updateAgenda/{idAgenda}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView update(@PathVariable("idAgenda") Integer idAgenda, Model atributos) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("agenda/atualiza-agenda"); 

    Agenda agenda = agendaService.buscarAgendaPorId(idAgenda); 

    model.addObject("agenda", agenda); 

    atributos.addAttribute("destinos", destinoService.buscarTodosDestinos()); 
    atributos.addAttribute("rotas", rotaService.buscarTodasRotas()); 

    return model; 
}
```

E no view:

```
<form:select path="idDestinoAgendamento" class="form-control">
    <option value="-1">Selecione o Destino</option>
    <c:forEach items="${destinos}" var="destino">
        <option value="${destino.idDestino}">${destino.nomeLocalDestino}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

O meu problema é que quando faço uma requisição POST na página o meu dropdown carrega novamente, não estou conseguindo recuperar o valor que estava.

Answer (score 1):

Foi resolvido. Estou usando o mesmo controller, só modifiquei o view:

```
<form:select path="idDestinosd" class="form-control">
    <option value="-1">Selecione o Destinos</option>
    <c:forEach items="${destinos}" var="destino">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${destino.idDestinosd eq agenda.destinosd.idDestino}">
                <option value="${destino.idDestino}" selected="true">${destino.nomeLocalDestino}</option>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <option value="${destino.idDestino}">${destino.nomeLocalDestino}</option>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```